# How to make Holes in Walls, connect Joints and make it symmetric / equal sides?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I started using Blender 4 days ago because I want to try and make games using Unity and Blender. I have 0 experience with code, Blender or Unity but I am eager to learn. So, to get me started I wanted to make some very simple buildings in blender and try and import them into Unity and make a cube run around in it (just to get a hold of the basics). Problem is that I have already run into my first problem major problems!

It took me two days to learn how to make this "hexagon labyrinth"-house", but now I have been stock 2 days without any progress, because I can't figure out how to do the next steps I need, and I have tried all kinds of things and watched **A LOT** of YouTube and read internet tutorials.

[image]
[image]

I have made this mesh model the following way:

**step 1 (floor):** added a cylinder-mesh with 6 vertices

**step 2 (center/outer walls):** added a tonus with 6 major segments and 6 minor segments and then used "dissolve edges" on the inner and outer edges to make it a "square" hexagon instead of "round" hexagon. Afterwards I made the same steps to make the outer wall as well, but just increased the major radius until it reached the “edge” of the floor

**step 3 (Halls/Corridors):** I made a tonus with 4 major segments and 6 minor segments and then used "dissolve edges" on the inner and outer edges to make it a "square" square instead of "round" square. Then I went into "edit mode" -> chose "face select", selected all the faces on one side and pulled the "faces" into the inner and outer hexagon walls so they overlapped with the "axis-arrows, green, blue, red (I don’t know what they are called)"

**step 4 (All halls):** Duplicated the mesh square tonus mesh from **step 3** six times and rotated them along the Z-axis so they overlapped the inner and outer hexagon walls as the 1st one to create the results you can see above

What I need to get done is the following:

[image]
**1st problem:** I need to clear a hole in the part of the outer and inner wall (1st and 2nd point as shown in the picture above)

**2nd problem:** I need to fill the "hole" between the corridors (3rd point as shown in the picture above)

**3rd problem:** I have tried to figure out how to delete/connect edges that overlap so they "become one". As you can see in the wire-mode the outer wall and floor is supposed to be connected (basicly work as 1 mesh), and yet I can't seem to have the top edge of the floor connect with the bottom edge of the hexagon wall and then have it merge into one. As for now I have made it "appear" as though the 2 meshes are 1 and the same, by sinking down the meshes 0.01 BU down on the Z-axis into the floor.

**4th problem:** I need everything to be 100% precise. Since I have "pulled" on the walls faces and rotated them I need to know the walls on each side of the inner hexagon are parallel with the wall on the opposite side, and that the space between each side of the halls/corridors are the same (4th and 5th point as shown in the picture above) and that all 6 halls are equally long.

**5th problem:** My thoughts about making a hole in a wall was to add edges to a part of the wall and then dissolve the 4 edges to “split” the wall, much like you can add points in a drawing programs, but I can’t seem to find a way to add edges to a mesh, making me wonder if it is even possible?

**6th problem:** I also thought about connecting 2 points/edges into 1 edge (like my overlapping walls). If I can overlap “lines” in blender, shouldn’t it be possible to make those “line” that overlap into an edge and the point where they overlap? Because if I could, it seems like a good way to solve almost all my other problems by connecting the lines into edges and then erase the surplus “line”

**7th problem** How to perfectly align sides and not just with (eye measure) seems to be an impossible job for me, I really can’t figure out how to do it, unless I got 2 mesh of exact same size, and use the coordinate system and even then I’m not always sure if they perfectly align because when I zoom in a lot it seems as they aren’t perfectly aligned (like how I wanted the outer faces of the floor hexagon, to perfectly align with the outer hexagon wall faces)

I know it’s a long list of problems, but I think it is better to ask now instead of wasting more days without getting anywhere and something tells me that my problems are probably easy to fix for veteran blender users, considering all I build is basically just walls and floor.

P.S I have tried to combine all the meshes into 1 with ctrl + J (which I kinda hoped would remove overlapping edges completely so it became 1 solid mesh) and doing stuff that way as well, but it didn’t really help, and even though I e.g. filled the gap between two walls (like in point 3) it looked, well, weird so and the color of the mesh became darker when I did it. I also tried to just use all kind of weird things to give the results I wanted, but the results are always weird.

I would like to have the lowest polycount at all, which is basicly what I am trying to achive.
If you need more pictures or anything just let me know!

*Thanks a bunch in advance to all who tries to help me, because I REALLY need the help!*

Comment: I think it's very hard to answer all your questions and anyway I would have used an array modifier with an empty as offset object to make this kind of object, but you say you've started Blender 4 days ago, why don't you follow some tutorials with simpler exercices?

Comment: Well I if this isn't easy, then I don't really see a future in Blender, I mean this is basicly just square object I want to put together and make with holes in them. How much simpler can it get? To be fair, THIS should be very very simple, so I can't see what else you suggest I make that should be simpler than this.

Comment: it is indeed very simple once you've found the right trick, it takes several minutes, but to learn the tools and to understand the logic that will make it simple is not simple, it takes months, and I don't think other 3D softwares are simpler

Comment: Which is why I ask for help to tell me the tricks. I don't need to learn a lot of features I won't need in blender. I need to learn the basic to make simple things in Blender. I don't plan to make complex figures, or sculp lifelike creatures. I only need to make low poly meshes and simple structures, which is something I (without knowing) think isn't really as complicated once you know which tools you need to use. I just need to know which tools. I don't need to learn the 10.000 other tools which I probably won't need or ever use :)

Comment: do you have a blueprint or a picture of the object?

Comment: I should have posted 3 pictures of model I have made in the post where I have drawn upon one of them

Comment: I could make what I wanted with just using **A LOT** of plane meshes, but that would just be an insane amount of time, when I know want I wanted could probably be made A lot after similarly to what I have done already, by using other meshes that just need some editing and removing some parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may not have put the walls and openings in the right place for you in this example, but as a general approach it might be useful... working in the flat on the floor-plan, before raising the walls.

[image]

1. Make a 6-sided circle, with all selected in edge mode. <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> subdivide to put a new vertex in the center of each edge, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> poke the face.
2. <kbd>I</kbd> inset the faces twice. The first inset is to allow us to bevel the outside edges, eventually, and the second inset marks the route of chamber-to chamber openings.
3. Select all the edges which may be corridors or openings, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel them to the width of your corridors.
4. Select all the edges which may become walls, (or define the width of the openings) and again, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> those edges to the width of your walls.
5. We can <kbd>Alt</kbd>-select the outer edge-loop, and <kbd>X</kbd> delete those vertices. Now select the faces you will want to raise to become walls
6. <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the walls out of your floor-plan.

Note you will have to do the extrusions of connected regions simultaneously, otherwise you will have internal faces.

To make a solid floor, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-select the outer edge-loop at floor level, and <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extrude it downwards. With the edges still selected, hit <kbd>F</kbd> to fill with an n-gon.

Comment: Mate I love you! thanks for the help, I will try and follow you guide! The model you made is EXACTLY as I wanted (except the placement of the holes). Quick question though, I can see you made a closed rectangle at the top part of the model. If selected the 4 edges and press "f" would it then fill up the hole inside, since it is closed? that is basicly the only part that is missing of my problems

Comment: If you wanted th kite-shaped area at the top to have a solid roof.. instead of extruding just the walls on its outer edges, select its whole region, and extrude as one piece.

Comment: Ahh okay :) fair enough

However, I think I fail to understand your very first step. I make a circle mesh with 6 side, but it's empty inside. So, I tried both "f" inside edit mode, but I also tried with all fill types ('triangle fan' and 'ngon') and then <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> but then I don't get those triangles you have in the first picture.

the "edge mode" you talk about in the 1st step. I think I fail to figure out what it is exactly

Comment: It's Ngon.. or, if you like, Empty, followed by F with all the edges selected. To get that set of edges with alt-P, you need to select all the edges first, and W>S subdivide them all  once (step 1). (Each edge needs an extra vertex in the middle of it)

Comment: Alrighty, so I got this far; https://imgur.com/bYOKYvm
However, the "I" botton confuse me a little, because sometimes it goes into this (where it makes another color and make weird shapes if I extrude it, where it have darker colours). What tool is this "I" ?

Secondly is there a way I can make sure everything is equal in side? While I can make walls now, how can I make sure the values are equal in size? like if all the walls are 1 unit thick?

Comment: the reason I ask is because I need the inner hexagon to be exactly one sixth of the outer hexagon :)

Comment: Your image shows overlapping faces, as if you have not selected the right edges to bevel before extruding. Have a play with the bevel tool on edges, and inset & extrude  tools on faces, using junk pieces of flat subdivided planes, etc. until you get the feel of what they do.. note the difference between extruding faces and edges.. The best way to get the inner hex exact would be to scale it  in edit mode before the bevel stage, while it is still bounded by a single line. I won't be able to get back until the morning now.. if you're still stuck, we'll move to chat.

Comment: I got it done thanks to you mate! It took a lot of fiddeling around, but it was only possible because of you introduction to all those functions you did in your guide!

one problem though, is I can't figure out how I find out the dimesions of each of the parts on the complete mesh (to make sure they are equal in sizes)

Comment: In the 3D view >  N property region, while in Edit mode, there's a 'Mesh Display' panel, with an edge > length option, which can show you. If you made all your bevels  of any particular width simultaneously they should be as close as floating-point allows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I got exactly the result I wanted thanks to the instructions I wanted by following Robin Betts' advice. It took some time and practice, but got want I wanted to create after a lot of different attempt and restarts of the program and fiddling around :)

(So, for anyone in the future who might fall over this post, just follow the steps posted by Robin

Comment: This post is very sweet of you, thank you, but it may get clobbered by the SE community for not strictly being an answer to the question. (SE is not a chat forum, it's strictly Q&A, part of whose function is to be an archive of useful answers). **If** an answer has worked for you on SE, the way to say that is to approve it